# moving "pieces" around the board with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I am working on a "simple" board game using create-react-app. I have a board component built from tiles. I want to move a pawn around the board in correlation to each player's position (position is saved and updated in each player's state object). Each of the tiles has a unique id. Essentially I want to make some kind of comparison check between the userPosition and the tile id, and render the user's pawn on the matching tile. 
I had thought of 2 ways to do this, both cumbersome, and neither quite working:

1. Have a pawn  for each user set inside each tile, and use CSS to toggle if they are visible or not.
2. Run a switch checking the userPosition, and updating the  CSS position property accordingly.

The problem with both those methods is that I need to be able to target DOM elements: in the 1st option I need to be able to check the id of each tile. In the 2nd option I need to be able to target the  element in order to change it's CSS position. using "regular" DOM methods like:

```
let myElement = document.getElementById("p1");
```

doesn't work.
I've been reading that maybe I need to be using a ref method, however I am using functional react with hooks, so I don't have a class to extend this to?

Also, I am totally open to other ideas as to how to visually move a pawn around the board, those are just 2 ideas I came up with.

some code:

the grid:

```
function Board () {




   return (


      <div className="boardContainer">
         <div className="row">
            <div className="col tile" id="1">
               *
            </div>
            <div className="col tile" id="2" >
               *
            </div>
            <div className="col tile" id="3">
               *
            </div>
            <div className="col tile" id="4">
               *
            </div>
            <div className="col tile" id="5">
               *
            </div>    
         </div>
```

the pawns:

```
<span className="dot1" id="p1"></span>
    <span className="dot2"></span>
    <span className="dot3"></span>
    <span className="dot4"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a *lot* of ways to do this without direct DOM manipulation.

You could have a `<Tile>` component that accepts a boolean value if a player is there and renders differently if one is:

```
function Tile({hasPlayer}) {
  return <div className="col tile">
    {hasPlayer ? <span className="dot1" /> : '*'}
  </div>
}
```

Now you could create a row like:

```
<div className="row">
  {[1,2,3,4,5].map(tileId => (
    <Tile hasPlayer={tileId === playerPosition} />
  )}
</div>
```

---

Or you could set the inline styles of the pawn to position the pawn absolutely.

CSS:

```
.pawn {
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 0.5s, top 0.5s; // smoothly move the pawn
}
```

If you knew the tiles were a certain size, say 50 pixels, you could then:

```
<span
  className="pawn"
  style={{
    left: playerPosition.x * 50,
    top: playerPosition.y * 50,
  }}
/>
```

---

In general, think about your game as pure data. You just have state that allows you to know about what happening in the game. Then you simply render that state.

Don't think of moving things on the web page. Simply update the data that records the game state, and then just render it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the last idea you suggested:     `  <span
  className="pawn1"
  style={{
    left: props.p1pos.x * 50,
    top: props.p1pos.y * 50
  }}
></span> ` in the board component, ``` .pawn1{
   position: absolute;
   transition: left 0.5s, top 0.5s;
   height: 15px;
   width: 15px;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
}``` in the CSS,  ``` p1pos={user1Data.userPosition} ``` passed as props, and finally ``` useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [user1Data]);``` as a listener, but the position is not being related.

Comment: so further experimentation shows that this works if I take the .x and .y away :)